# GEE: Export to Asset using a multipolygon

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I have some analysis im doing for a boreal-wide model that requires SAR composites. As I'm covering a very large geographical domain I have split my data up into 90km tiles. I'd like to export my data to asset using the tiles I have. The tiles and a portion of my data can be seen here:

[image]

Now I have 83 of these tiles so am looking for the best way to export the data this way. I currently have a rather inefficient for loop that clips my data per polygon (tile) and exports it:

```
for(var a = 1; a < exportArea.size().getInfo() + 1; a++){
var poly = exportArea.filter('OBJECTID == ' + a)
var clipped_data = s1_vv_vh_gamma_2020_frozen_pwr.clip(poly)
Map.addLayer(clip_shape, {min:0.01,max:0.3})

Export.image.toAsset({
image: clipped_data,
description: 's1_vv_vh_gamma_2020_frozen_pwr_' + a,
assetId: 's1_vv_vh_gamma_2020_frozen_pwr_' + a,
scale:30,
crsTransform: [[30, 0.0, 0, 0.0, -30, 0]],
maxPixels:1e13
})}
```

but is there a better way of doing this? For one tile the process is fairly fast (an hour or two for export) but running one of the tasks when I do it this way takes >12 hours

Comment: I'm not sure, but I'd try to explicitly specify `region` when exporting. Perhaps you ended up exporting the whole area (with a ton of masked pixels) instead of just your polygon.